# Logical Statement Added to Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, logical-operators

I need a logical statement added to my current formula (that i received here) and i need an addition to it.

The example as shown below is me trying to receive the number 1 if there is more than one A in a row. the issue i ran into is that i need to have this remain blank IF a specific cell has any value. Here that cell is represented by the number 10 right before the formula.
[image]

I tried using ISBLANK but i only received a false or true statement. I still would like it to appear as a 1 if there are more than one A's in a line and blank if it is false with the addition of not counting it if there is a number in a specific cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I got Your problem right, but sounds like You could apply the AND() operation like:

```
 IF(AND(COUNTIF(A115:BC116,"A")+COUNTIF(A115:BC116,"a")>2;BE116="");"1";"")
```

If BE116 is the Range of the cell which shall be empty for counting.

Comment: This brings back an error with excel that says the formula is broken and then highlights the 2

Comment: Use `,` rather than `;` (this is a Excel regional version issue, some language versions use `;`)

Comment: This still returns an issue; however, now the entire formula is highlighted when it returns the error.